# Ofstream writes empty file on linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ofstream

I have a program which writes its output using ofstream. Everything works perfectly fine on Windows when compiled with Visual Studio, but it only writes empty file on Linux when compiled with GCC.

```
ofstream out(path_out_cstr, ofstream::out);
if(out.bad()){
 cout << "Could not write the file" << flush;
}
else{
 cout << "writing";

 out << "Content" << endl;

 if(out.fail()) cout << "writing failed";

 out.flush();
 out.close(); 
}
```

The directory which is being writen into has 0777 privileges.

The weird thing is: nothing is written, but no error is reported.

The gcc --version is: (Gentoo 4.3.4 p1.0, pie-10.1.5) 4.3.4

I'm aware the code SHOULD work, so I'm more like looking for suggestions, what could be wrong, than for direct code-fix.

EDIT: fwrite seems to fail in exactly the same fashion (nothing is writte, no error is reported).

EDIT: i'm exectuing both the GCC and the program over SSH on my university directory, if it can have any significance. I have sufficient permisssions to exectute and write files (ls . > out.txt works just fine), it only my program which has trouble.

Thanks for help

Comment: Works for me under FC12 with g++ 4.4.3

Comment: what's the output (as in cout) of your program under Linux?

Comment: Did you check a free space in your directory (df -h dirname)? I'd also run the program under *strace* and see what syscall failed.

Comment: maybe the file was already there, empty, and doesn't have write permissions? do you remove it every time before running it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the file is there or is not, it always ends up empty.

Comment: Ist this all the code ? Are you sure there's no code elsewhere that opens/truncates the file again ?

Comment: Could it be that your program doesn't have enough privileges..? - unfamiliar with unix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Works for me, ubuntu g++-4.1.
Have you tried to execute `strace ./test` and see if there are `write()` calls over the file?

Comment: Yes, the write calls are there

Comment: the write calls are there? Then there is nothing to do with the code. :S  
I guess `cat "something" > test_file` works?

Comment: Oh, now I see there is "Disk quota exceeded" hidden in the strace output. Thanks for help, I didn't know strace.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely solution is that the file is failing to open in the constructor due to a problem in the name or path. If the file can't be opened, the `failbit` rather than the `badbit` bit would be set so test for that rather than using `bad()` :

```
ofstream out(path_out_cstr, ofstream::out); 
if(out.fail()){ 
    cout << "Could not write the file" << flush; 
...
```

`fail()` checks if either failbit or badbit is set whereas bad just checks for badbit. BTW I tried your example and it worked no problem so I deliberately made the path bad - still no problem, but when I changed to `fail()` it picked up on the bad path.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is being created, I can see know reason why it would not be written.

Check the value of `path_out_cstr`. On Unix-like systems, paths are separated with forward slashes '`/`' rather than the MS-DOS-style backslash'`\`', which may explain the difference in behaviour between the two operating systems.

---

**Updated**

Since we failed to `catch` the `failbit` | `badbit` problem for a time, you may wish to `try` the exception handling approach... this sample will halt after reporting the first failure...

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* const path_out = argv[1];

    std::cerr.exceptions(std::cerr.goodbit);

    std::ofstream the_file_stream;
    the_file_stream.exceptions(the_file_stream.badbit | the_file_stream.failbit);

    try
    {
        std::cerr << "Opening [" << path_out << "]" << std::endl;
        the_file_stream.open(path_out);

        std::cerr << "Writing" << std::endl;
        the_file_stream << "Content" << std::endl;

        std::cerr << "Flushing" << std::endl;
        the_file_stream.flush();

        std::cerr << "Closing" << std::endl;
        the_file_stream.close();
    }
    catch (const std::ofstream::failure& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failure: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the path_out_cstr is command line argument to the program, so it is what I type into it. Also, I guess if the path was wrong, the file would not be even created.

Comment: You're right, of course. I've provided some sample code which may help catch similar errors in future.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with g++ 4.4.1

Comment: The gcc --version is:

(Gentoo 4.3.4 p1.0, pie-10.1.5) 4.3.4

I'm aware the code SHOULD work, so I'm more like looking for suggestions, what could be wrong, than for direct code-fix.

Comment: @commanderz: I doubt it's a code problem. Have you tried to change the output directory?